# Python Flask Server generating too many new threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a Python Flask server running on Python 3.6.6 that generates new threads for some reason. This is my code:

```
# Packages and Modules
import os
import threading, time
from config import config
from Modeller.Modeller import Modeller

# Job scheduler function
def run_job(Modeller, config):
    while True:
        print("Run recurring task")
        print(threading.enumerate())
        modeller = Modeller(config) # Initiate modeller with config
        modeller.run()
        time.sleep(modeller.config['settings']['delay'])

# Start thread for calling function repeatedly
thread = threading.Thread(name='modelling', target=run_job, daemon=True, args=[Modeller, config])
thread.start()
```

The first log generates:

```
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140381841954560)>, <Thread(modelling, started daemon 140381169248000)>]
```

But after a few runs it generates:

```
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140381841954560)>, <Thread(modelling, started daemon 140381169248000)>, <Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 140381017106176)>, <Thread(Thread-2, started daemon 140380804740864)>, <Thread(Thread-3, started daemon 140380796348160)>, <Thread(Thread-4, started daemon 140380786644736)>, <Thread(Thread-5, started daemon 140380778252032)>]
```

The only threads that should be listed are MainThread and modelling? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does this code relate to Flask? What is calling or importing this?

Comment: I think you should provide the full code to show how this code used with Flask.

Comment: Do you override the threading config of Flask? Do you start new threads in `modeller.run`?